# 2 instances of same view controller : one does not work in the TabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

I tried many options, but none of them work. The problem is simple :

I have got one UITabBarController, which works perfectly for 5 tabs.

My problem is located on first and second tabs : I need to use the same view controller under each tab, but of course with 2 distinct instances.

I tried to add 2 distinct navigation controllers, all pointing to the same view controller as root controller. This way I can customize the tab text and icon (I work mainly in interface builder for this) on each navigation controller.

```
              __ NavController 1 _
             /                    \
TabController -- NavController 2 -- ViewController
```

With this configuration : only the first tab works (the one handled by NavController1), the second does not show the view (I absolutely don't know which view is shown, but it's empty, black and has a default empty blue nav bar). If I keep only one link from navigation controller to my view controller, like this :

```
             __ NavController 1 
             /                    
TabController -- NavController 2 -- ViewController
```

The second tab works perfectly !

The other option is to link the NavController twice, but in this case I need to configure title and image programmatically depending on the tab index and I am not sure where would be the place to do this.

So :

- Is this normal behaviour ?
- Is there a solution with IB ?
- If I need to programmatically setup the tab appearances, where should I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code similar to this in your app delegate, if you want to do it programatically.

```
UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];


MyViewController *mvc1 = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
MyViewController *mvc2 = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
mvc1.title=@"One";
mvc2.title=@"Two";
mvc1.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
mvc2.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"two.png"];


UINavigationController *nc1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mvc1];
UINavigationController *nc2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mvc2];


[tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nc1,nc2, nil]];


self.window.rootViewController = tbc;
```

Comment: Ok thank you ! I see, that means I need to setup all the tabbar programmatically. I can do that... I think it was the "old way" of doing it before Apple added this feature in the storyboard editor. Just waiting to check if I got a solution with the interface builder before validating an answer. Anyway thank you for your fast reply !

Comment: Look, this is weird : when I setup the tab bar programmatically as you proposed, one of my TableViewController does no longer retrieve my prototype cells (by calling [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId]), it always return nil. I assume there is something different when allocating the controller through [[... alloc] init] as opposed to when the storyboard instantiates it. At the moment I could not find it, I got no specific init method. I keep on investigating, but if you have any tips ;)

Comment: OK I found it : the solution is to instantiate objects from the main storyboard, I used :
    UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    
    MasterViewController *placesView = [st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"masterListView"];

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in IB. Just add two navigation controllers as the base controllers of two of the tabs, add root view controllers to each of them (not just one like you showed in your question), and change the class of those root view controllers to your subclass.

**After Edit**

If you have a complicated scene that you made as one of the root view controllers, you can copy and paste it, and another one will appear in the objects list on the left side of the IB window (and on the canvas as well, but it's right on top of the other one, so you need to drag it off to see it). You can connect a second navigation controller to it. You can either do it that way, or drag in two different UIViewControllers and change them both to your subclass (if you need different looking interfaces for the 2 different instances).

Comment: Mmmm, looks like what I did : I added a root view controller to each of them, but the root is the same view controller for both navigation controllers. And it does not work...because it is the same view controller. Just as if it is not possible to have a same view controller declared as the root of 2 distinct navigation controllers...at least in this scenario with a tabbarcontroller.

Comment: @ChristopheFondacci, I don't know what you mean by the same -- did you make a connection between the 2 navigation controllers to the same view controller scene? If so, that's not what I said to do. I added 2 navigation controllers, deleted the tableViewControllers that you get by default as the root view controllers, dragged out TWO new view controllers, hooked one up to each navigation controller, and changed the class of those two controllers to my subclass. It works fine -- if I put a button in each one, and have it log self, I see that they are 2 different instances of the same class.

Comment: @ChristopheFondacci, see my edit, there's 2 different ways that I accomplished this in IB.

Comment: OK, indeed this is not what I did but it does not work for me : copy/paste is not an option since it duplicates the view, and I need changes to be reflected on every version. Adding 2 new view controllers and binding to the same class is not an option either, because I need my original look'n feel, not only my controller implementation... Unfortunately I think that programmatic method is the only way to go, although I do not understand why connecting 2 different nav controllers to the same view controller as their root does not work. I think it might be a bug, what do you think ?

Comment: @ChristopheFondacci, "Adding 2 new view controllers and binding to the same class is not an option either, because I need my original look'n feel" I have no idea what you mean by this. You said you wanted them to be instances of the same controller -- if you drag out 2 controllers and change their class to your subclass that's what you get. You can make the interfaces as similar or as different as you want. There's nothing in the code answer above that does anything different than what I'm telling you to do in the storyboard.

Comment: If I drag out 2 controllers, I get 2 different interfaces. Even if they initially look the same, they are copies. I need them to be the same (not only the controller class). With your method (drag 2 times) when I make a modification on one interface, it is not replicated in the second... this is not what I want. The only way is the programmatic way. I confirm that it IS different than your solution because I can keep a single interface for both tabs.